# How can I filter a wordpress page based on content?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm making a custom module via plugin for a page builder (Divi). I want to be able to allow php code in the content of the page if they use this module on the page, but obviously don't want to allow this on all pages. I can't figure out how to identify that the module is being used so that I can apply a filter. Any ideas?